# How to create a CombinedChart with bars and lines?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). How to create the multisets bar chart series in combined chart where i am combining bar chart and line chart

here is my code, please have a look

```
   private BarData generateBarData(List arrayList){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        BarData barData = new BarData();
        for(int counter=0;counter<arrayList.size();counter++)
        {
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(20.0f,counter));
        }

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Bar Dataset");
        barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        barDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60,220,78));
        barDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);
        barData.addDataSet(barDataSet);
        barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        return barData;
    }
private LineData generateLineData(ArrayList arrayList){
        ArrayList<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        LineData lineData = new LineData();
        for(int counter=0;counter<arrayList.size();counter++)
        {
            lineEntries.add(new Entry(20.4f,counter));
        }
        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries,"Line Dataset");
        lineDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(240,238,70));
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        lineDataSet.setCircleSize(5f);
        lineDataSet.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(true);
        lineDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);
        return  lineData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CombinedChart`, multiple `BarDataSets` are not supported in versions prior to **v3.0.0**.

As of [**release v3.0.0**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases) multiple bars are supported in the `CombinedChart`.

Comment: can you please let me know when you expect this to be working @philipp

Comment: @Philipp Is there an update on this? Do you have an idea when this may be ready?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda I am unable to reduce width for bar dataset.